# "if-else" with multiple OR / Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, operators, conditional-statements

I have a question and I have not been able to find an answer.
Is there any way to reduce the following expression in Objective-C?

```
if ((r != 1) && (r != 5) && (r != 7) && (r != 12)) {
   // The condition is satisfied
}else{
   // The condition isn't satisfied
}
```

For example (not working):

```
if (r != (1 || 5 || 7 || 12)) {
   // The condition is satisfied
}else{
   // The condition isn't satisfied
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could remove some of the parenthesis.

Comment: It would be a longer expression, but you could create an array of ints with 1, 5, 7, and 12 and check if it contains `r`. More code but slightly more maintainable.

Comment: try yo read about De Morgan laws.

Comment: If you're in control of the values you're comparing, you could make it a mask as well and then use bitwise operations to check the values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `NSSet`, like this:

```
NSSet *prohibited = [NSSet setWithArray:@[@1, @5, @7, @12]];
if (![prohibited containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:r]]) {
    // The condition is satisfied
} else {
    // The condition isn't satisfied
}
```

If the set of numbers contains a fixed group of numbers, such as in your example, you can make the `NSSet *prohobited` a static variable, and initialize it once, rather than doing it every time as in my example above.

Comment: Since you are already using the modern syntax, you could also create the NSNumber using `@(r)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `switch` for this like

```
switch (r)
{
    case 1:
    case 5:
    case 7:
    case 12:
        // r is having 1,5,7 or 12
        break;
    default:
        // r is having other values
}
```